# Babun displaying old version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, babun

I am trying to check the current version of Python(3.7.0) using Babun. However, it is displaying an old version(2.7.8). I am not getting the problem when using the Windows Command Prompt.

Windows Command Prompt

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Gauranga Das>python --version
Python 3.7.0

C:\Users\Gauranga Das>
```

Babun

```
LAPTOP-298AIKEQ% python --version
Python 2.7.8
LAPTOP-298AIKEQ%
```

Answer (score 1):

In a babun shell run:

```
pact install python3
```

Then run update.bat inside the babun folder which will reinstall cywin. (Can't run update.bat from inside babun shell as all babun shells need to be closed for the reinstall to work):

```
update.bat
```

Now we can see the python 3 version by running:

```
python3 --version
```